# Brute force implementation for 0-1 Knapsack

Tags: c, algorithm, knapsack-problem

I'm struggling with the given task for almost a week without success of finding solution so this site is my last hope.

I have [0-1 Knapsack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0-1_knapsack_problem) problem which has 20 items with different values and weights, maximum weight of sack is 524. Now i need to implement brute force to find optimal solution subset of 20 items so that total weights <= 524 and maximum values of chosen items.

Could you please point me out or better give detailed implementation to analyze how it work!!
Thank you very much

Comment: yes this is homework and i'm stuck at how to find all possible combinations, should i store combinations to array?

Answer (score 6):

The brute-force idea is easy:

1. Generate all possible subsets of your 20 items, saving only those which satisfy your weight constraint. If you want to be fancy, you can even only consider subsets to which you cannot add anything else without violating the weight constraint, since only these can possibly be the right answer. O(2^n)
2. Find the subset with maximum weight. linear in terms of the number of candidates, and since we have O(2^n) candidates, this is O(2^n).

Please comment if you'd like some pseudocode.

EDIT: What the hey, here's the pseudocode just in case.

```
  GetCandidateSubsets(items[1..N], buffer, maxw)
  1. addedSomething = false
  2. for i = 1 to N do
  3.    if not buffer.contains(item[i]) and
           weight(buffer) + weight(items[i]) <= maxw then
  4.       add items[i] to buffer
  5.       GetCandidateSubsets(items[1..N], buffer)
  6.       remove items[i] from buffer
  7.       addedSomething = true
  8. if not addedSomething then
  9.    emit & store buffer
```

Note that the GetCandidateSubsets function is not very efficient, even for a brute force implementation. Thanks to amit for pointing that out. You could rework this to only walk the combinations, rather than the permutations, of the item set, as a first-pass optimization.

```
  GetMaximalCandidate(candidates[1..M])
  1. if M = 0 then return Null
  2. else then
  3.    maxel = candidates[1]
  4.    for i = 2 to M do
  5.       if weight(candidates[i]) > weight(maxel) then
  6.          maxel = candidates[i]
  7.    return maxel
```

Comment: (1) finding maximum weight is `O(2^n)` as well, since you need to check all subsets. (2) the main advantage of backtracking and bruteforce is usually space complexity, by storing all possibilities, your space complexity is `O(2^n)` and you lose this advantage. (3) the solution in your pseudocode is not `O(2^n)`, it is `O(n!)`, or even `O(n^n)`

Comment: @amit: Right, getting the maximum element would be O(2^n) since there are O(2^n) subsets to check and the maximum-element-finding code looks at them all. The second criticism isn't all that meaningful to me, since the OP doesn't really indicate this is a concern. The criticism in (3) is noted; for what it's worth, I didn't put a lot of work into this code.

Comment: hi note that if subset A has 1000 values and 523 weights and B has 999 values and 524 weights then A must be optimal solution

Comment: @FinalIllusion: Yeah, right. Even if the pseudocode somehow doesn't get the right answer, the method outlined in points 1 and 2 is clearly a sure solution to the problem. If my GetCandidateSubsets is inefficient or, as you seem to suggest, incorrect, search StackOverflow for *any* function to generate subsets from a set of elements. Any of them will do. Throwing out subsets that aren't "full" according to the weight limit is simply an optimization to reduce the candidate subset space.

Comment: @Patrick87: thank you for pseudo-code! Could you please write implementation in detail in c. I think i learn more rather than pseudo-code